# What is $_POST used for

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

I am trying to add information into my DB using php. Examples and tutorials use `$_POST` to do this.

How may I check the value(s) of `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, or any php variables using the Ubuntu terminal (if there even is a way to do this)?

Comment: While I'm unsure on the technical specifics, $_GET puts arguments in the url, while $_POST obscures them. $_POST is generally more secure because arguments don't appear in the URL or history. You may have better luck at a different exchange, maybe one related to programming instead of ubuntu

Comment: Since the POST data only exists for a request from a client to a server, specify which of both you're using.

Comment: @muru I want to know where these variables are stored in apache2, and how I can check there values using ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` is what is known as 'server variables', 'global variables' or 'super globals' in PHP. It is used by PHP to collect the form inputs of your HTML form after form submission. These form inputs are usually collected using a variable.

Example:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

Now these variables viz. `$name` & `$city` can be used in your SQL query to enter form data into the database. For detailed explanation and examples you may visit the following link: [Insert records in a MySQL table using PHP](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php).